# "Патрон" вместо "патронов"

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

В одной приключенческой книге для подростков упорно и многократно встречается *"осталось **пять патрон"***.  Школьные знания и интернет говорят мне, что множественное число родительного падежа — "патронов".
Возможно, это диалектный вариант или какой-то жаргонизм, как "договора" или "компАс"?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Интересно, одна ли такая книга: автор не Вячеслав Жуков? Там это не речь персонажа, а прямо в авторском тексте. Второе, что находится - карикатура с репликой иностранки, и тоже про ровно "пять патрон", будто это магическое количество или устойчивое сочетание.

Comment: Нет, Олег Верещагин. Похоже, это диалектное и неосознанное, потому что по тексту встречается и этак, и этак, см. комментарий к ответу @slava1947.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно, это диалектный вариант или какой-то жаргонизм?

В словаре Горбачевича *"Трудности словоупотребления и варианты норм русского литературного языка. Словарь-справочник"* (Л.,  1974) род. падеж мн. ч. ***"патрон"*** назван **просторечным**.

См. у Шолохова *("Тихий Дон")*:

> – Винтовкой не разживусь у тебя? Нету лишней?
>
> – На что тебе?
>
> – Для дому. И от зверя, и от худого человека. На всякий случай.
>   **Патрон**-то я целый ящик взял.

Ну а у Жукова можно встретить не только *"осталось **пять патрон**".* Есть и *"**против полтора десятка** вооруженных бандюков"*, и *"**И так**, я жду ответа"*, и...

Наверное, это **его** язык.

Comment: Да, наверное это так. Посмотрел - в нескольких книгах этого автора повторяется такое. При этом, у него то: "Ну-ка… - он выдвинул ящик стола, достал пять плоских магазинов и яркие коробочки мелкокалиберных патронов к верхнему стволу", то "Снарядив точными движениями пальцев все магазины, Рат подумал и положил рядом с ними одну из коробочек - на сто патрон.", то "Но вместо того, чтобы вернуться к снаряжению патрон, мальчик подпёр голову рукой и задумался…"

Answer (score 0):

Это просторечное, вряд ли диалектное.

Причем это не родительный падеж вообще, а т. н. (по Зализняку) счетная форма. Используется только в сочетании с числительными. В выражениях типа "не осталось патронов" она невозможно. Этим, видимо, и объясняются "колебания"  в авторском тексте.

Хотя вот тут и в настоящем родительном:
"Но вместо того, чтобы вернуться к снаряжению патрон, мальчик подпёр голову рукой и задумался" - вот это даже не просторечие, а просто ошибка.